# Build Docker image using Ansible Playbook (with multi-target Dockerfile)

Tags: docker, ansible, devops

Is there any option how to implement Docker command (`--target` parameter)

```
docker build --target backend -t project/backend:latest
```

in Ansible Playbook with `docker_image` module? Right now in playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Build backend image
      docker_image:
        path: /var/lib/workspace/project/backend
        name: project/backend:latest
```

Comment: You can patch [docker_image](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/docker/docker_image.py).

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
---
- name: Copy Dockerfile
  copy: src=Dockerfile dest=/tmp/path/
- name: Build osquery image
    docker_image:
      path: /tmp/path/
      name: imagename
      tag: v1
```

Comment: I don't quite see how the --target is used in this example. Could you explain your answer a bit, @sudheerchamarthi?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Ansible it is possible to define the target in `docker_image`.

[Ansible Documentation - community.docker.docker_image](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#ansible-collections-community-docker-docker-image-module)

I think this should work for you

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Build backend image
      docker_image:
        path: /var/lib/workspace/project/backend
        name: project/backend:latest
        target: backend
```

When the Dockerfile is something like

```
FROM for-example-php-image AS baseimage 
# Common things

FROM baseimage AS backend
# Things needed only in backend
```